# How are timeouts set for AndroidAsync websockets?

Tags: java, android, websocket, androidasync-koush

I am trying to change the default AndroidAsync websocket initial connection timeout of 30 seconds. This is the working version with the default timeout:

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket(connectionURI.toString(), null, this);
```

I would like to change the timeout. This is what I expected to work:

```
int timeout_ms = 20000;
AsyncHttpGet request = new AsyncHttpGet(connectionURI.toString());
request.setTimeout(timeout_ms);
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket(request, null, this);
```

This results in an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid uri=ws://exampleserver.com:80/test middlewares=[com.koushikdutta.async.http.HttpTransportMiddleware@1e2543c8, com.koushikdutta.async.http.spdy.SpdyMiddleware@2534fc61, com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncSocketMiddleware@107b3386]`

Note that exactly the same connectionURI string is successful in the first case, but not the second.

Is there a way to change the timeout of the AndroidAsync websocket?

Answer (score 0):

This hack helped me.You need to pass http or htpps protocol.

```
    AsyncHttpGet request = new AsyncHttpGet("ws://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8500".replace("ws://", "http://").replace("wss://", "https://"));
    request.setTimeout(3000);

    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance();
    asyncHttpClient.websocket(request, null, webSocketConnectCallback);
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be unresolved issue by Koush
https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/340

Comment: how this issue is related to the timeout issue?